# Proof for uniform convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I was given this problem:

[image: Problem]

These are my calculations and I'm asking for verification:

Pointwise limit:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\frac{1}{x^n}+x^{n}} = 1$

Uniform convergence:

$\mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)\mid = \mid f_{n}(x) - 1\mid = \mid\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} -1 \mid= \mid \frac{x^{n}}{\frac{1}{x^n}+x^{n}} - \frac{\frac{1}{x^n}+x^{n}}{\frac{1}{x^n}+x^{n}}\mid = \mid -\frac{\frac{1}{x^n}}{\frac{1}{x^n}+x^{n}}\mid =  \frac{\frac{1}{x^n}}{\frac{1}{x^n}+x^{n}} \leq \frac{1}{x^n}$

Thus:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} sup\{\mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)\mid : x \in [R, \infty)\} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^n} = 0.$

From this follows that $f_n(x)$ is uniform convergent

Comment: I think the last line should be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup$ and not $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty}$.

Comment: Yeah it should.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x \in [R, +\infty)$, we find that, since $R > 1$, therefore we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ x^{2n} }{ 1 + x^{2n} } \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{x^{2n}} + 1} \\
&= \frac{1}{0+1} \qquad [\mbox{ as $x \geq R > 1$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{2n}} = 0$ } ]\\
&= 1.
\end{align}
$$
Now let $f \colon [R, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the formula
$$
f(x) \colon= 1 \qquad \mbox{for all } x \in [R, +\infty). \tag{0}
$$
Then the sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges *pointwise* to the function $f$ on $[R, +\infty)$.

Let us now check if this convergence is uniform.

We note that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x \in [R, +\infty)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} - 1 \right\rvert \\
&= \left\lvert \frac{-1}{1+x^{2n}} \right\rvert \\
&=  \frac{1}{\left\lvert 1+x^{2n}  \right\rvert } \\
&= \frac{1}{ 1+x^{2n}  } \\
&< \frac{1}{x^{2n} } \\
&\leq \frac{1}{R^{2n}}. \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Now as $R > 1$, so 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{R^{2n}} = 0.
$$

Thus from (2) we can conclude that, given a real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a natural number $N = N(\varepsilon)$ such that 
$$
\left\lvert \frac{1}{R^{2n}} - 0 \right\rvert = \frac{1}{R^{2n}} < \varepsilon
$$
for any natural number $n > N$. In fact, we can take $N$ to be any natural number greater than the quantity
$$
\begin{cases} 
\frac{ - \ln \varepsilon }{ \ln R} \ \mbox{ if } \varepsilon \neq 1, \\
1 \ \mbox{ if } \varepsilon = 1.
\end{cases}
$$

So using (1) we can conclude that, given a real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a natural number $N$ such that 
$$
\left\lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \right\rvert < \varepsilon 
$$
for all $ x \in [R, +\infty)$ and for any natural number $n > N$.

Hence the sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ indeed converges *uniformly* to the function $f$ defined by the formula (0) above.

Answer (score 0):

You have written "$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = f_n(x) - 1$". That is not correct. The RHS is negative.

---

To do it, an easy way is to note that for every $n \in \Bbb N$, the function $f_n$ is increasing on $[R, \infty)$. And also that $f_n(x) < 1$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x \le R$.

Now, you know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(R) = 1.$$
So, given any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $|f_n(R) - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.
Since $f_n(R) \le f_n(x) < 1$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x > R$, it follows that
$$|f_n(x) - 1| < \epsilon,$$
for all $x > R$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, as desired.

---

**EDIT:** This is after the post was edited.
You write

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup\{\mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)\mid : x \in [R, \infty)\} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\color{#FF0000}x^n} = 0.$$

It should actually be

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup\{\mid f_{n}(x)-f(x)\mid : x \in [R, \infty)\} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\color{#FF0000}R^n} = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if corrected my calculations. Does it work like this

Comment: Have updated my answer as well.